# Wix v3.7 - Error Writing Registry Values

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, registry, wix3.7

I'm creating an installer using wix and I'm having problems writing to the registry. Here is my RegistryValue element:

```
<Component Id="CMP_odbcreg" Guid="{115B002E-F4C9-48CD-8E1C-E8803B16AE69}">
        <RegistryValue Id="rg_psql" 
                       Root="HKLM" 
                       Key="SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers" 
                       Name="PostgreSQL" 
                       Value="Installed" 
                       Type="string" 
                       KeyPath="yes" 
                       Action="write"/>
</Component>
```

Nothing is being written to the registry. This component is in my main install feature, so it should always write to the registry. I looked at my log file and found this:

```
MSI (s) (60:1C) [00:00:07:080]: Doing action: WriteRegistryValues
MSI (s) (60:1C) [00:00:07:080]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 0:00:07: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
Action start 0:00:07: WriteRegistryValues.
WriteRegistryValues: Key: Writing system registry values, Name: , Value: 
Action ended 0:00:07: WriteRegistryValues. Return value 1.
```

I don't know if I'm interpreting that right, but it seems like nothing is being written to the registry at all. I have several other components generated using heat that contain RegistryValue elements which should have been executed in addition to CMP_odbcreg. I checked my Windows Registry and confirmed that no values are being written.

I have a wix manual which contains an example of writing to the registry. I tried copying and pasting it into my installer and adding it to the main install feature. That didn't work either

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was looking at the wrong registry. Windows 7 machines have a 32 bit AND a 64 bit registry, so I should have been looking at the regedit.exe found in Windows\SysWOW64.

Answer (score 0):

Since nowadays 64 bit systems are widely spread I recommend a small lecture on [Registry Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), I am sure you will find the info useful for the future. This applies to any application accessing the registry, not just to an installer.

In your case, if you need to disable the redirection for the installer, you can have a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947372/disable-registry-redirection-in-wix).